# Encoding non UTF-8 text in Parameters in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, encoding, internationalization

#### Background

I have a web application that uses `ISO-8859-1` encoding. When I pass parameters using `Html.ActionLink()`, the value is decoded to `UTF-8`:

`Web.config`:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"
               fileEncoding="iso-8859-1" />
```

`Index.aspx`

```
This is a <%= Html.ActionLink("test", "Read", new { name="Cosméticos" }) %>
```

generates the following:

```
This is a <a href="/Intranet/Read?name=Cosm%C3%A9ticos">test</a>
```

The problem is the value I receive in my controller is `UTF-8`, not `iso-8859-1`:

`TestController`:

```
public ActionResult Read(string name) {
  //name is "CosmÃ©ticos" here!
}
```

#### Question

Why the string is not decoded to `Cosméticos`?

Comment: Thanks, George - that's much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and the workaround: the value I receive is UTF-8, but if I try to use System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(name) it converts the characters "Ã©" to UTF-8 values instead of "É".

The workaround is to copy the string to a byte[] and then use System.Text.Encoding.Convert().

I don't know if this is the best way, but now everything is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Does your aspx files are physically saved in iso-8859-1?

"File / Save Xyz As" And click at the right of the save button to have more encoding options to save your file in..

A guess

Comment: Yes, my files are saved in iso-8859-1. But I don't think this is the problem, because "Cosméticos" is coming from my database.

Comment: The thing with encodings, it have to strictly be the same across each layer of your app., or be converted from one to another if there's a mismatch between 2 layers. Does your DB is in iso-8859-1? Maybe yes, but maybe values were in UTF-8 before putting them in!? Try to convert your DB values in iso-8859-1 when outputting to you aspx pages to see if it helps.. You have to find the step where the encoding breaks and it could be somewhere else before your MVC action parameters.

Comment: Also, I run a french/english site so I have lots of latin characters. I prefer using UTF-8 anyway to cover a broader range of characters.

Comment: My db is in iso-8859-1 format. But as you can see in my Index.aspx file, the string is correctly url encoded so it doesn't matter anymore if my file or db is saved in iso-8859-1. It seems that the problem is when the framework decodes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string ActionLinkNoEncode(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, ActionResult action )
{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);   
    var url = Uri.UnescapeDataString(urlHelper.Action(action)).ToLowerInvariant();  
    var linkTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");   
    linkTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);
    linkTagBuilder.InnerHtml = linkText;
    return linkTagBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you might want to consider.

First, if you haven't already read it -- I highly recommend reading Joel Spolsky's article ['The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)'](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) It sets the stage for learning about character encoding and programming.

Second, looking at [the docs on the globalization element in the web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) it sounds like there are ways to (accidentally?) override the specified encoding scheme.  From the docs:

> **requestEncoding**
>
> Specifies the assumed encoding of each incoming request, including
> posted data and the query string. If the request comes with a request
> header containing an **Accept-Charset** attribute, it overrides the
> requestEncoding in configuration. The default encoding is UTF-8,
> specified in the `<globalization>` tag included in the Machine.config
> file created when the .NET Framework is installed. If request encoding
> is not specified in a Machine.config or Web.config file, encoding
> defaults to the computer's Regional Options locale setting. In
> single-server applications, **requestEncoding** and **responseEncoding**
> should be the same. For the less common case (multiple-server
> applications where the default server encodings are different), you
> can vary the request and response encoding using local Web.config
> files.

Have you tried using something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to **see what the Accept-Charset attribute is set to**?